# Dynamic field selectors based of previous selected field - Kentico 10

Tags: field, multi-select, kentico

I have two fields on one of my page types. I want my content team to be able to 
choose one field from a drop-down and have that previously selected field determine which multi-select items show up on the next field below.

Comment: So what is the problem ? Where are you stuck ? What have you  tried?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about cascading dropdown.

Have a look at this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fapq-8GIQU0) it should put you on the right track.

Basically on the main/parent field you need to tick the "**Has depending fields**" and on the child field "**Depends on other field**" is ticked.

In the values of the child field you can access the parent value via Macro and dynamically load the values you need to display based on the parent selection.

Comment: Perfect. That’s what’s I needed!

Comment: The only issue I am having with following the youtube video is where do I actually store the list data so that I can retrieve it from the field? Would it be inside the Kentico dbo ?

Comment: you basically need to have 2 DataSources with some sort of relation ship between them. Like in the case of the youtube video they were using Built In County List in Kentico as the primary and the Cascading part was the State List. In the State List table each items it linked to the country by its ID. If you can give some indication of the type of data you have and the relation ship between them I may be able to provide more specific details on how to achieve it.